# Insert html in DynamicPopoverTitle Angular

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, angularjs

Here's my haml file:

```
.new-project{"ng-controller" => "PopoverCtrl"}
  %a{"popover-placement" => "right", :popover => "{{dynamicPopover}}", "popover-title" => "{{dynamicPopoverTitle}}"} + New Stream
```

And for my popover.js.coffee

```
App.controller("PopoverCtrl", ($scope) ->
    $scope.dynamicPopover = 
    $scope.dynamicPopoverTitle = "<span class='text-info'><strong>Create New Stream</strong></span>'+
                '<button type='button' id='close' class='close' onclick=''>&times;</button>'"
)
```

But it's showing my html tags as strings.

See screenshot: http://d.pr/i/nMA5

Comment: you should sanitize it if your plugin doesnt do it by default

Comment: How to sanitize it? I tried using `raw` but no luck

Comment: see the $sanitize provider

Comment: Sorry my first time to use angular.

Answer (score 0):

Hi solved this by creating a custom directives.

**popOverdirectives.js.coffee**

```
Bento.directive "popOver", ($compile) ->
  title = '<span class="text-info"><strong>Create New Stream</strong></span>'+
          '<button type="button" id="close" class="close" onclick="$(&quot;div.popover&quot;).hide();">&times;</button>'
  formTemplate = "<label for='project_name'>Stream Name</label>
                 <br/>
                 <form ng-submit='createStream()'>
                 <input autofocus='autofocus' class='form-control' id='project_name' name='project[name]' placeholder='Untitled Stream' required='required' type='text', ng-model='newProject.name'>
                 <br/>
                 <input type='submit' value='Create' class='btn btn-md btn-success'>
                 </form>"
  getTemplate = (contentType) ->
    template = formTemplate
  transclude: true
  template: "<span ng-transclude></span>"
  controller: "PopoverCtrl"
  link: (scope, element, attrs) ->
    popOverContent = undefined
    if scope.items
      html = getTemplate("items")
      popOverContent = $compile(html)(scope)
    options =
      content: popOverContent
      placement: "right"
      html: true
      title: title

    $(element).popover options
```

`html:true` is the key :)